When I upgrade to CXF from 3.x to 4.x why does the LogEvents use a different name?
I have the following code to test some CXF logging
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
    List<LogEvent> logEvents = LogEventManager.INSTANCE.getEvents(LoggingOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    assertEquals(4, logEvents.size());

I noticed this broke when I went to 4.x like
Expected: an instance of ...RestServiceException
     but: <java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<4> but was:<0>> is a java.lang.AssertionError
Stacktrace was: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<4> but was:<0>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)

When I debug both I notice the 3.x LogEvent has a name org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor but the 4.x has a value org.apache.cxf.services.GreetingApi.REQ_OUT
Why did this change and can someone point me to the release notes that show this?
Also extra points if you can tell me how to get the REQ_OUT when I refactor like
       List<LogEvent> logEvents = LogEventManager.INSTANCE.getEvents(GreetingApi.class.getName());
